# display google line chart (image) with single value

Tags: html, google-visualization, linechart

I am using the [deprecated Google Line chart (image)](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/line_charts?hl=es-) in my website. Using this chart I am creating differnt reports. If it has only one value, it does not display the chart value. But I want to display that single value in Line Chart by default.

With the common Google Line chart I set the "'pointSize': 3" and I solved the problem, but with image api, I dont know if it is posible

this is my example of the chart with only one value:

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=200x125&chd=t:40
[image]

Anyone knows how to do something like that?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do a bit more clearly. I don't understand what you want to do. You want a line chart with point size 3? A chart with 1 value? You want the image chart as an SVG chart so you can use point size?

Comment: Line markers can be set with [this option](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/chart_params?hl=es-#gcharts_shape_markers) if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well you should try adding something like this:

&chm=o,,0,,5.0

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=200x125&chd=t:40&chm=o,,0,,5.0